# Regex rule in PHP to check for any subdomain

Tags: php, regex, cross-domain

I am trying to check or validate subdomains/domain using Regex, check this is what I want:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == "^(.*\.?domain\.com)$"){
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}
```

So, if the subdomain is: es.domain.com, en.domain.com, etc.domain.com, domain.ws, test.com then I can print the header policy.

More Explanation: I have several subdomains (around 40) and two more domains (Total, 3 domains) and I need to know if $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is equal to one of this domain or subdomain, if is equeal then I print the header policy.

I want to do this with a regex because if I place the subdomains/domains in a list this will be too long. Any help ?

Resume: I have three domains:  domain.com, domain.ws and test.com (which subdomains for each one) that I would like to past this validation.

Answer (score 3):

Well, PHP has the `preg_*` functions for use with regex. In your case:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:.+\.)?domain\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
```

If you want to be more specific about the allowed domains and subdomains (allowing any combination - I assume the second-level domains are aliases):

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:(?:es|en|etc)\.)?(?:domain\.com|domain\.ws|test\.com)$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
```

Will allow any of the host names you mentioned.

Alternatively, you could allow *any* subdomain and domain, [capture them](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and check them afterwards. Suppose you have an array of allowed subdomains and an array of allowed second-level domains.

```
preg_match('/^(?:(.+)\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $matches);
$subdomain = $matches[1];
$domain = $matches[2];
if((!$subdomain || in_array($subdomain, $subdomainArray)) &&
   in_array($domain, $domainArray))
{
    ...
}
```

[`preg_match` documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Thanks m.buettner for your response. The first code help me as I wanted, but only for one domain (domain.com). the other ones that I putted are not the ones that I need, maybe I did a mistake making to understand that the only diference was numbers. The other two domains (apart of "domain.com") looks more like: "domain.ws" (and "subdomains") and ".test.com" (and "subdomains"). I will edit my question placing that.

Comment: Not really, because I have too many subdomains not only es|en|etc, also if I create another subdomain then I will have to edit this rule as well. The first one works perfect, but only for one domain, is there a way to do something similar but for the three domains ?

Comment: @Saymon I've made another edit that shows a different approach. Any set of parentheses (that does not start with `?:`) will create an element in the `$matches` array with what was matched inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_match("/".addcslashes($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"],"/")."\/(\w+)\//",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"],$d);

$sub = $d[1];
```